# Attach Debugger to Android process option is missing

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio-4.0

"Attach Debugger to Android process" is missing in Android Studio 4.0 Canary 7

Here is the screenshot [image]

Comment: Created Issue tracker with Google - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146758524

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue. If you have flutter plugin enabled then disable and restart android studio and the option will come back.

Or if you aren't using flutter then you can find "attach debugger to process" option under "run" tab.